# How can I force the assumption that a symbol is a vector of n zeros

Tags: assumptions

Using

```
$Assumptions = Element[n, Integers] && Element[a, Vectors[n, Reals]]
```

I can assume that a is a n-dimensional vector of Reals. How can I assume that a is a n-dimensional vector of zeros?

I tried adding this to the assumptions

```
Norm[a] == 0
```

such that the assumptions now look like this

```
$Assumptions = Element[n, Integers] && Element[a, Vectors[n, Reals]] && Norm[a] == 0
```

Since a is a vector and only the 0 vector has a Norm of zero, mathematica should now know that a is a vector of n zeros. However,

```
Refine[3*a]
```

returns `3 a` instead of 0.

Comment: Why not simply define your vector to be what you seek?  `a = Table[0,{n}]`

Comment: I suspect that the question is about cases where n is a parameter/variable? I for one am curious about how Vectors[n, Reals] even works: does Mathematica ever respect the use of a symbol for the dimensionality or is Vectors[] meant for vectors whose size you know beforehand only?

Comment: "Since a is a vector and only the 0 vector has a Norm of zero, mathematica should now know that a is a vector of n zeros" is a very dubious assertion.

Comment: @m_goldberg I think that assumption is strictly true. The norm is zero iff the vector is zero. But `Refine` simply doesn't use the norm.

Comment: @Jens. The dubious part of the quote is "mathematica should now know".

Comment: @m_goldberg Ah, thanks for clarifying that. I think the question needs clarification because the motivation for starting with that particular assumption is not given. That could help find a useful answer even if `Norm` as an assumption doesn't work so directly.

Comment: The motivation is that I want to do calculations with a matrix that has a lot of zero entries. My idea is to use a to represent this entries. The zero entries should be of arbitrary size n. I would like to do the calculation without specifying a specific n to get a general result.